# CoreLocation - significant change

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Is it possible to use more than one coreLocation service at the same time? For example, significantLocationChange and visits together

Answer (score 0):

Recommend is use *singleton* class for *locationManager* and use throughout the app.

Are else battery will be drain.

```
import CoreLocation


let manager = CLLocationManager()       
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
manager.delegate = self
manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
             
manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

Try this.

Comment: I want to use visits, significant, geofencing together.

Comment: yes, Everything will be is possible by using singleton class.

Comment: Are you sure that combining different location services with a single CLLocationManager instance will work fine ?

Comment: yes. that will work. Because of your will get a current location only. where every I get in project.